# Connecting Home Assistant to PLC using modbus

Tags: modbus, plc, modbus-tcp, home-automation, home-assistant

I’m using PFC200 from Wago to automate my home. The blinds and lights are working fine, I got a lot of scenes implemented in the PLC. Now I would like to visualize the state of lights and be able to turn them on/off from HA. HA will be just as a visualization tool - everything else is on the PLC.

I wanted to connect to my PLC using modbus but I’m having a lot of problems with configuration.
First of all, I’m always getting the following error:

```
2021-05-19 08:23:41 ERROR (SyncWorker_1) [homeassistant.components.modbus.modbus] Pymodbus: Modbus Error: [Connection] ModbusTcpClient(192.168.10.60:502): Connection unexpectedly closed 0.000071 seconds into read of 8 bytes without response from unit before it closed connection
```

Data are actually read but this error is always there spamming logs.

And the second problem is the data refresh time. I was investigating the PLC and the modbus is working fine there, updating the data immediately but it is not reflected in HA even I have `scan_interval: 2`.

Here is my configuration:

```
modbus:
  - name: PLC
    type: tcp
    host: 192.168.10.60
    port: 502

switch:
  - platform: modbus
    scan_interval: 2
    coils:
      - name: fake_switch
        hub: PLC
        slave: 1
        coil: 0
      - name: switch.bedroom_main_light
        hub: PLC
        slave: 1
        coil: 1
      - name: switch.bedroom_wardrobe_light
        hub: PLC
        slave: 1
        coil: 2
      - name: switch.bathroom_main_light
        hub: PLC
        slave: 1
        coil: 4
      - name: switch.bathroom_mirror_light
        hub: PLC
        slave: 1
        coil: 5

light:
  - platform: switch
    name: Bedroom
    entity_id: switch.bedroom_main_light
  - platform: switch
    name: Wardrobe
    entity_id: switch.bedroom_wardrobe_light
  - platform: switch
    name: Bathroom
    entity_id: switch.bathroom_main_light
  - platform: switch
    name: Bathroom - Mirror
    entity_id: switch.bathroom_mirror_light
```

Maybe I should go with the registry instead of the coil? Can someone share his working configuration?

Comment: I would recommend using WAGO DALI module. That would save a lot of time.

Comment: @SergeyRomanov You completely misunderstood my question. It is not about turning on/off light or implementing light/blinds scenes as I got all of this implemented in Structured Text. What I want to do is just a visualization, nothing more...

Comment: You completely misunderstood my answer. DALI has already UI built in or you have a lot of ready solutions to connect to DALI server and build UI by drag&drop.

Comment: @SergeyRomanov With your comment now I'm sure - you don't get what I was asking for sure :D